# Program rebus (VBA)

Tags: knowledge, rebus, movies

The code snippet below in VBA contains all the clues to find an old movie quote. Who said it, and in what movie?

```
Public Function Try(Action as String)
   Select Case Action
      Case "Do"
         Msgbox("Just do it!")
      Case Else
         Msgbox("Don't do it!")
   End Select
End Sub
```

Hint:

> Language of code isn't really relevant. Although an attempt to compile might put you on the right track.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Answer

> "Do. Or do not. There is no try.". Yoda - Star Wars The Empire Strikes Back

Explanation:

> The case handles 2 branches only. `Do` where it alerts "Just Do it". For any other value of `Action` it alerts "Don't do it". There is no other option.

Comment: I had a hunch it was too easy, but couldn't resist putting it up :)

Comment: @TimCouwelier Indeed it was too easy. I haven't seen the movie (bow head in shame) and still know the quote and where is it from. :)

Comment: Can you explain the hint aswell?

Comment: @TimCouwelier. Done.

Comment: Close, but I'll accept it anyway. The intended clue was in the name of the function 'try'. You build a return for a function try(), by having a statement 'try = "Just do it"'. No such statement would probably thrown an error, stating there's no return statement ('there is no try').

Comment: @TimCouwelier lol, this was my guess for the other one, because I mistakenly just skimmed it