# Time to unlearn. What's this movie quote?

Tags: rebus, computer-puzzle, movies, computer-science

This Java snippet describes a quote from a movie. Can you find the quote?

```
void function (int number, int attempts) {

  {
    if (number > 1) {
      do {
        System.out.println('something');    
      } while (attempts > ++number);
    } else {
      System.out.println('something else');
    }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println('something bad');
  }

}
```

Comment: Where is the try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29858/program-rebus-vba

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that before I posted. The answer is indeed the same, but the riddle itself seems different enough to me.

Comment: I can't really agree about the duplicate.  Sure, it's the same answer, but it's a different programming language, a different style, and a completely different method of getting that answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quote:

> Do, or do not.  There is no try.

Explanation:

> The "catch" is missing the corresponding "try" statement, regardless of how the "do while" evaluates.